# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_10 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (19316,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am running a CNN that check for images but does not classify. In fact, the output layer is a dense layer that have as argument the size of the images in the labels in 1d.

As shown below in the code, I am using model.fit_generator() instead of model.fit and when it comes to start training the model the following error comes up:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_10 to have shape 
(1,) but got array with shape (19316,)
```

Why is this an error? The output of my dense is an array of 19316 elements, why does it expect it to have a shape of (1,) ?

Here attached is also the summary of the model :

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv2d_28 (Conv2D)           (None, 26, 877, 32)       544

---

activation_37 (Activation)   (None, 26, 877, 32)       0

---

max_pooling2d_28 (MaxPooling (None, 13, 438, 32)       0

---

conv2d_29 (Conv2D)           (None, 12, 437, 16)       2064

---

activation_38 (Activation)   (None, 12, 437, 16)       0

---

max_pooling2d_29 (MaxPooling (None, 6, 218, 16)        0

---

conv2d_30 (Conv2D)           (None, 5, 217, 8)         520

---

activation_39 (Activation)   (None, 5, 217, 8)         0

---

max_pooling2d_30 (MaxPooling (None, 2, 108, 8)         0

---

activation_40 (Activation)   (None, 2, 108, 8)         0

---

flatten_10 (Flatten)         (None, 1728)              0

---

dropout_10 (Dropout)         (None, 1728)              0

---

dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 19316)             33397364

=================================================================

Total params: 33,400,492
Trainable params: 33,400,492
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
def generator(data_arr, batch_size = 10):

num = len(data_arr) 

if num % batch_size != 0 : 
    num = int(num/batch_size)

# Loop forever so the generator never terminates
while True: 

for offset in range(0, num, batch_size):

    batch_samples = (data_arr[offset:offset+batch_size])

    samples = []
    labels = []

    for batch_sample in batch_samples:

        samples.append(batch_sample[0])
        labels.append((np.array(batch_sample[1].flatten)).transpose())

    X_ = np.array(samples)
    Y_ = np.array(labels)

    X_ = X_[:, :, :, newaxis]

    print(X_.shape)
    print(Y_.shape)

    yield (X_, Y_)

# compile and train the model using the generator function
train_generator = generator(training_data, batch_size = 10)
validation_generator = generator(val_data, batch_size = 10)

run_opts = tf.RunOptions(report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom = True)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), input_shape = (55, 1756, 
1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(8, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature 
vectors
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(19316))

model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'adam',
              metrics = ['accuracy'],
              options = run_opts)

model.summary()

batch_size = 20
nb_epoch = 6

model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                    steps_per_epoch = len(training_data) ,
                    epochs = nb_epoch,
                    validation_data = validation_generator,
                    validation_steps = len(val_data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss, which needs integer labels and does the one-hot encoding internally, but your labels are already one-hot encoded.

So for this case you should revert back to the `categorical_crossentropy` loss.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, but how do you see that the labels are one-hot encoded? @Matias Valdanegro

Comment: @lr99 "but got array with shape (19316,)" this indicates one-hot encoding, as 19316 is the number of classes

Comment: thanks a lot for your help @Matias Valdanegro ! Just one last question: how do I convert the argument of the last dense layer to be not one-hot encoded? Thanks a lot in advance